# Troubleshooting Elastic Beanstalk instances that fail to start successfully

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I have a small Elastic Beanstalk environment, used /very/ infrequently for demos, set up that has worked for years.

As of December 7th (as I said, it was used very infrequently), there's been a problem: an instance will start, and a few minutes later will be terminated.  Since it's now below the autoscale properties, it'll start another instance...which will terminate a few minutes later.  This has apparently been repeating for the last 6 weeks.

To the best of my knowledge, nothing has changed in the environment since September of last year.

Retrieving the logs via the Elastic Beanstalk dashboard returns a cfn-init.log that includes this:

```
2018-01-19 21:58:42,290 [DEBUG] Writing content to /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/download_source_bundle
2018-01-19 21:58:42,290 [DEBUG] Retrieving contents from https://s3.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-env-resources-us-east-1/eb_patching_resources/download_source_bundle.py
2018-01-19 21:58:42,342 [DEBUG] Setting mode for /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/download_source_bundle to 000750
2018-01-19 21:58:42,343 [DEBUG] Setting owner 0 and group 0 for /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/download_source_bundle
2018-01-19 21:58:42,343 [DEBUG] Running command 01downloadVersion
2018-01-19 21:58:42,343 [DEBUG] No test for command 01downloadVersion
2018-01-19 22:00:26,265 [ERROR] Command 01downloadVersion (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/download_source_bundle) failed
2018-01-19 22:00:26,268 [DEBUG] Command 01downloadVersion output: 
2018-01-19 22:00:26,269 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of Infra-WriteApplication2: Command 01downloadVersion failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 505, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 241, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 103, in apply
    raise ToolError("Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command 01downloadVersion failed
2018-01-19 22:00:26,273 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 01downloadVersion failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 135, in <module>
    worklog.build(detail.metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 117, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 496, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 505, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 241, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 103, in apply
    raise ToolError("Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command 01downloadVersion failed
```

Unfortunately, I don't see any more details about why this command failed anywhere, in any of the logs.  I've verified that the download_source_bundle.py file it's trying to download is valid.

I'm not 100% that the above command is what is causing the termination, but I see no other errors in the logs.  Googling for the string "Error encountered during build of Infra-WriteApplication2: Command 01downloadVersion failed" returns people asking similar questions, and then saying that it was due to IAM permissions...however, the IAM permissions have not changed since at least September.  Other lines in the log refer to installing RPMs from https://s3.amazonaws.com, so I do not believe it is an outbound network issue.

So, the questions:

1. Is there anything that can explain why this would've suddenly occurred without environment changes?
2. Is there a way for me to get more information about why the command failed?
3. If it's possible that the command isn't the thing responsible for instances being terminated, where else would I look?

Comment: One other thing to check, is that the instance can connect to the internet. I had a similar error and it ended up being a misconfiguration with the VPC private / public subnetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, stop thinking "nothing has changed". Obviously, something has changed, otherwise it would work. The change may be yours, or it may be AWS's, but something has changed.

Based on the error `Command 01downloadVersion failed`, there appears to be an issue downloading the version from the S3 bucket that stores it to the EC2 instance.

This issue can be any of:

- Permissions are insufficient to download the version, or
- The version has been deleted from the S3 bucket.

Elastic Beanstalk stores the application versions in S3.

You can use the following command to see where in S3 your applications are storing the data:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-application-versions
```

In the response, find the version corresponding to the one your appliacation is currently using. There, you'll see something like the following:

```
"SourceBundle": {
    "S3Bucket": "my-bucket",
    "S3Key": "path/to/my/version.zip"
}
```

Look there to make sure that the data has not been deleted.

Barring that, double check the IAM permissions are correct for the EC2 instance to download the version from the S3 bucket and that the S3 bucket does not have a bucket policy preventing the downloading of the file.

Comment: You were correct.  The version had been deleted from S3 (due, I believe, to a lifecycle event).  Your answer was very helpful.